# default location for single primary shard on elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES 7.8 cluster to store log data, one index for one tenant.

[image]

As you can see [the default index.number_of_shards](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#_index_creation_no_longer_defaults_to_five_shards) is one. (Please ignore the fact I dont have any replicas because the data are just imported)

This looks problematic as all primary shards are located on the same node. How can I assign them evenly on different nodes when creating the index?

Update1:

```
$ curl -sk 'myhost:19081/_cluster/settings?pretty'
{
  "persistent" : { },
  "transient" : { }
}


$ $ curl -sk 'myhost:19081/_cluster/allocation/explain?pretty&include_disk_info=true&include_yes_decisions=true'
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "unable to find any unassigned shards to explain [ClusterAllocationExplainRequest[useAnyUnassignedShard=true,includeYesDecisions?=true]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "unable to find any unassigned shards to explain [ClusterAllocationExplainRequest[useAnyUnassignedShard=true,includeYesDecisions?=true]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}


$ curl -sk 'myhost:19081/_cat/nodeattrs?v'
node     host          ip            attr              value
node-001 10.96.110.92  10.96.110.92  ml.machine_memory 99750834176
node-001 10.96.110.92  10.96.110.92  ml.max_open_jobs  20
node-001 10.96.110.92  10.96.110.92  xpack.installed   true
node-001 10.96.110.92  10.96.110.92  transform.node    true
node-004 10.96.108.179 10.96.108.179 ml.machine_memory 99531649024
node-004 10.96.108.179 10.96.108.179 ml.max_open_jobs  20
node-004 10.96.108.179 10.96.108.179 xpack.installed   true
node-004 10.96.108.179 10.96.108.179 transform.node    true
node-003 10.96.113.19  10.96.113.19  ml.machine_memory 99531649024
node-003 10.96.113.19  10.96.113.19  ml.max_open_jobs  20
node-003 10.96.113.19  10.96.113.19  xpack.installed   true
node-003 10.96.113.19  10.96.113.19  transform.node    true
node-002 10.96.112.213 10.96.112.213 ml.machine_memory 99531649024
node-002 10.96.112.213 10.96.112.213 ml.max_open_jobs  20
node-002 10.96.112.213 10.96.112.213 xpack.installed   true
node-002 10.96.112.213 10.96.112.213 transform.node    true
node-005 10.96.101.214 10.96.101.214 ml.machine_memory 99516563456
node-005 10.96.101.214 10.96.101.214 ml.max_open_jobs  20
node-005 10.96.101.214 10.96.101.214 xpack.installed   true
node-005 10.96.101.214 10.96.101.214 transform.node    true


$ curl -sk 'myhost:19081/_all/_settings?include_defaults&filter_path=**.allocation&pretty'
{
  // with several hundreds other identical results of indices
  "my_index_1" : {
    "defaults" : {
      "index" : {
        "routing" : {
          "allocation" : {
            "enable" : "all",
            "total_shards_per_node" : "-1"
          }
        },
        "allocation" : {
          "max_retries" : "5",
          "existing_shards_allocator" : "gateway_allocator"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Update2:

```
curl -sk -HContent-Type:application/json -d ' {"index": "my_index_1", "shard": 0, "primary": true }' 'myhost:19081/_cluster/allocation/explain?pretty&include_disk_info=true&include_yes_decisions=true'

{
  "index" : "my_index_1",
  "shard" : 0,
  "primary" : true,
  "current_state" : "started",
  "current_node" : {
    "id" : "CNyCF4_eTmCQYXh_Bhb0KQ",
    "name" : "node004",
    "transport_address" : "10.96.108.179:9300",
    "attributes" : {
      "ml.machine_memory" : "99531649024",
      "ml.max_open_jobs" : "20",
      "xpack.installed" : "true",
      "transform.node" : "true"
    },
    "weight_ranking" : 1
  },
  "cluster_info" : {
    "nodes" : {
      "CNyCF4_eTmCQYXh_Bhb0KQ" : {
        "node_name" : "node004",
        "least_available" : {
          "path" : "/data3/nodes/0",
          "total_bytes" : 15999772393472,
          "used_bytes" : 23527976960,
          "free_bytes" : 15976244416512,
          "free_disk_percent" : 99.9,
          "used_disk_percent" : 0.1
        },
        "most_available" : {
          "path" : "/data2/nodes/0",
          "total_bytes" : 15999772393472,
          "used_bytes" : 19824119808,
          "free_bytes" : 15979948273664,
          "free_disk_percent" : 99.9,
          "used_disk_percent" : 0.1
        }
      },
      "xiR8clLRSVirvkmlyDpgXg" : {
        "node_name" : "node001",
        "least_available" : {
          "path" : "/data1/nodes/0",
          "total_bytes" : 15999896125440,
          "used_bytes" : 2815332352,
          "free_bytes" : 15997080793088,
          "free_disk_percent" : 100.0,
          "used_disk_percent" : 0.0
        },
        "most_available" : {
          "path" : "/data3/nodes/0",
          "total_bytes" : 15999896125440,
          "used_bytes" : 278740992,
          "free_bytes" : 15999617384448,
          "free_disk_percent" : 100.0,
          "used_disk_percent" : 0.0
        }
      },
      "afbAZaznQwaRtryF7yI4dA" : {
        "node_name" : "node003",
        "least_available" : {
          "path" : "/data1/nodes/0",
          "total_bytes" : 15999836385280,
          "used_bytes" : 34533376,
          "free_bytes" : 15999801851904,
          "free_disk_percent" : 100.0,
          "used_disk_percent" : 0.0
        },
        "most_available" : {
          "path" : "/data1/nodes/0",
          "total_bytes" : 15999836385280,
          "used_bytes" : 34533376,
          "free_bytes" : 15999801851904,
          "free_disk_percent" : 100.0,
          "used_disk_percent" : 0.0
        }
      },
      "vhFAg67YSgquqP8tR-s98w" : {
        "node_name" : "node002",
        "least_available" : {
          "path" : "/data1/nodes/0",
          "total_bytes" : 15999836385280,
          "used_bytes" : 34537472,
          "free_bytes" : 15999801847808,
          "free_disk_percent" : 100.0,
          "used_disk_percent" : 0.0
        },
        "most_available" : {
          "path" : "/data1/nodes/0",
          "total_bytes" : 15999836385280,
          "used_bytes" : 34537472,
          "free_bytes" : 15999801847808,
          "free_disk_percent" : 100.0,
          "used_disk_percent" : 0.0
        }
      },
      "KL8hcVTJTBmN9MTa3fX8eQ" : {
        "node_name" : "node005",
        "least_available" : {
          "path" : "/data1/nodes/0",
          "total_bytes" : 15999772393472,
          "used_bytes" : 34983936,
          "free_bytes" : 15999737409536,
          "free_disk_percent" : 100.0,
          "used_disk_percent" : 0.0
        },
        "most_available" : {
          "path" : "/data1/nodes/0",
          "total_bytes" : 15999772393472,
          "used_bytes" : 34983936,
          "free_bytes" : 15999737409536,
          "free_disk_percent" : 100.0,
          "used_disk_percent" : 0.0
        }
      }
    },
    "shard_sizes" : {
      "[my_index_1][0][p]_bytes" : 2120083,
      // redact several hundreds others 
    },
    "shard_paths" : {
      "[my_index_1][0], node[CNyCF4_eTmCQYXh_Bhb0KQ], [P], s[STARTED], a[id=dqceFOaFT0ugDALnFEJWvg]" : "/data2/nodes/0",
      // redact several hundreds others 
    }
  },
  "can_remain_on_current_node" : "yes",
  "can_rebalance_cluster" : "yes",
  "can_rebalance_to_other_node" : "no",
  "rebalance_explanation" : "cannot rebalance as no target node exists that can both allocate this shard and improve the cluster balance",
  "node_allocation_decisions" : [
    {
      "node_id" : "KL8hcVTJTBmN9MTa3fX8eQ",
      "node_name" : "node005",
      "transport_address" : "10.96.101.214:9300",
      "node_attributes" : {
        "ml.machine_memory" : "99516563456",
        "ml.max_open_jobs" : "20",
        "xpack.installed" : "true",
        "transform.node" : "true"
      },
      "node_decision" : "worse_balance",
      "weight_ranking" : 1,
      "deciders" : [
        {
          "decider" : "max_retry",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "shard has no previous failures"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "replica_after_primary_active",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "shard is primary and can be allocated"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "enable",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "all allocations are allowed"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "node_version",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "can relocate primary shard from a node with version [7.8.0] to a node with equal-or-newer version [7.8.0]"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "snapshot_in_progress",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "no snapshots are currently running"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "restore_in_progress",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "ignored as shard is not being recovered from a snapshot"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "filter",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "node passes include/exclude/require filters"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "same_shard",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "this node does not hold a copy of this shard"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "disk_threshold",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "enough disk for shard on node, free: [14.5tb], shard size: [2mb], free after allocating shard: [14.5tb]"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "throttling",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "below shard recovery limit of outgoing: [0 < 2] incoming: [0 < 2]"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "shards_limit",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "total shard limits are disabled: [index: -1, cluster: -1] <= 0"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "awareness",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "allocation awareness is not enabled, set cluster setting [cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes] to enable it"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "node_id" : "afbAZaznQwaRtryF7yI4dA",
      "node_name" : "node003",
      "transport_address" : "10.96.113.19:9300",
      "node_attributes" : {
        "ml.machine_memory" : "99531649024",
        "ml.max_open_jobs" : "20",
        "xpack.installed" : "true",
        "transform.node" : "true"
      },
      "node_decision" : "worse_balance",
      "weight_ranking" : 1,
      "deciders" : [
        {
          "decider" : "max_retry",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "shard has no previous failures"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "replica_after_primary_active",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "shard is primary and can be allocated"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "enable",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "all allocations are allowed"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "node_version",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "can relocate primary shard from a node with version [7.8.0] to a node with equal-or-newer version [7.8.0]"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "snapshot_in_progress",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "no snapshots are currently running"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "restore_in_progress",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "ignored as shard is not being recovered from a snapshot"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "filter",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "node passes include/exclude/require filters"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "same_shard",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "this node does not hold a copy of this shard"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "disk_threshold",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "enough disk for shard on node, free: [14.5tb], shard size: [2mb], free after allocating shard: [14.5tb]"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "throttling",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "below shard recovery limit of outgoing: [0 < 2] incoming: [0 < 2]"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "shards_limit",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "total shard limits are disabled: [index: -1, cluster: -1] <= 0"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "awareness",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "allocation awareness is not enabled, set cluster setting [cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes] to enable it"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "node_id" : "vhFAg67YSgquqP8tR-s98w",
      "node_name" : "node002",
      "transport_address" : "10.96.112.213:9300",
      "node_attributes" : {
        "ml.machine_memory" : "99531649024",
        "ml.max_open_jobs" : "20",
        "xpack.installed" : "true",
        "transform.node" : "true"
      },
      "node_decision" : "worse_balance",
      "weight_ranking" : 1,
      "deciders" : [
        {
          "decider" : "max_retry",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "shard has no previous failures"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "replica_after_primary_active",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "shard is primary and can be allocated"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "enable",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "all allocations are allowed"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "node_version",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "can relocate primary shard from a node with version [7.8.0] to a node with equal-or-newer version [7.8.0]"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "snapshot_in_progress",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "no snapshots are currently running"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "restore_in_progress",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "ignored as shard is not being recovered from a snapshot"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "filter",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "node passes include/exclude/require filters"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "same_shard",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "this node does not hold a copy of this shard"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "disk_threshold",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "enough disk for shard on node, free: [14.5tb], shard size: [2mb], free after allocating shard: [14.5tb]"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "throttling",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "below shard recovery limit of outgoing: [0 < 2] incoming: [0 < 2]"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "shards_limit",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "total shard limits are disabled: [index: -1, cluster: -1] <= 0"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "awareness",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "allocation awareness is not enabled, set cluster setting [cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes] to enable it"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "node_id" : "xiR8clLRSVirvkmlyDpgXg",
      "node_name" : "node001",
      "transport_address" : "10.96.110.92:9300",
      "node_attributes" : {
        "ml.machine_memory" : "99750834176",
        "ml.max_open_jobs" : "20",
        "xpack.installed" : "true",
        "transform.node" : "true"
      },
      "node_decision" : "worse_balance",
      "weight_ranking" : 1,
      "deciders" : [
        {
          "decider" : "max_retry",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "shard has no previous failures"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "replica_after_primary_active",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "shard is primary and can be allocated"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "enable",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "all allocations are allowed"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "node_version",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "can relocate primary shard from a node with version [7.8.0] to a node with equal-or-newer version [7.8.0]"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "snapshot_in_progress",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "no snapshots are currently running"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "restore_in_progress",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "ignored as shard is not being recovered from a snapshot"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "filter",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "node passes include/exclude/require filters"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "same_shard",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "this node does not hold a copy of this shard"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "disk_threshold",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "enough disk for shard on node, free: [14.5tb], shard size: [2mb], free after allocating shard: [14.5tb]"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "throttling",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "below shard recovery limit of outgoing: [0 < 2] incoming: [0 < 2]"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "shards_limit",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "total shard limits are disabled: [index: -1, cluster: -1] <= 0"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "awareness",
          "decision" : "YES",
          "explanation" : "allocation awareness is not enabled, set cluster setting [cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes] to enable it"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the response you get from running `GET _cat/nodeattrs?v` and `GET _all/_settings?include_defaults&filter_path=**.allocation` ?

Comment: @Val I updated the post. Please take a look. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks can you replace the second output with the one you get from `GET /_cluster/allocation/explain?pretty&include_disk_info=true&includeYesDecisions=true`

Comment: @Val Also I should mention that our DBA gave an alternate http url to connect to ES, rather than the default node:9200. Looks like a reverse proxy of some sort.

Comment: @Val I updated the second output. Please have a look. TIA

Comment: Can you add the following body to the allocation explain call `{
  "index": "my_index_1",
  "shard": 1,
  "primary": true
}` and try again?

Comment: @Val Hi, I appended info with "update2". Quite long output, and I removed some of the outputs for sensitive reasons.

Comment: @Val sorry to ask but if you need any other outputs please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out my cluster has a `cluster.routing.allocation.balance.shard` of zero.

Solved this by

```
PUT /_cluster/settings 
{ 
  "persistent" : { 
    "cluster.routing.allocation.balance.shard" : "0.45" 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch by default tries to spread the shards evenly on all the data-nodes, in your case its really strange why all the shards all on the same data-node.

You should debug the cause of it, hopefully you don't have a single data-node in your cluster, please provide your cluster settings in order to get more information on your cluster settings and setup.

Also provide the output of [Shard allocation explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-allocation-explain.html).

For time being, You can manually move these shards on other data-nodes by using the [cluster reroute API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html)

Comment: Hi, I updated the post with cluster setting and allocation explain api.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch automatically take cares of allocating shards to different node.
Try to rebalance cluster that may fix the problem
[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html#:~:text=Elasticsearch%20runs%20an%20automatic%20process,from%20completely%20balancing%20the%20cluster](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html#:%7E:text=Elasticsearch%20runs%20an%20automatic%20process,from%20completely%20balancing%20the%20cluster).

Comment: maybe I can rebalance them later but how can I prevent then from been allocated on the same node from the beginning?